# Can't round the corners of menus for gtk?

Tags: gtk

I've been searching everywhere on how to round the corner of the right-click context menus. Every other widget in GTK can have rounded corners but context menus for some reason. Why is it that this is much more difficult than any other widget? I've tried modifying the css styles  for Ambience in gtk-widgets.css, but the rounding attributes do not apply.

Why isn't there any rounding support for context menus? I've read that I have to enable rgba support for context menus, so how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You need a theme engine supporting round corners. Old gtk2 Murrine does, as you can see in this [Murrine-based theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/RGBA+Gtk%2B+module?content=100556) on gnome-look.org.

Comment: The little tut says I should put it in the `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0` folder, but I don't think Quantal has this directory. Sigh, why can't I have Mac OS X's nice rounded context menus.